# Java ProcessBuilder Syntax for Initial construction with Command

Tags: java, syntax, processbuilder

I am trying to run a command which I give my ProcesBuilder as parameter while constructing.

The command is the following:

```
wmic process where name='OUTLOOK.EXE' get CommandLine
```

I normally just would run it with a pb.command() but I need to "catch" the output which I already did via a BufferedReader.

So my question is how I can do the Syntax right if I want to do something like:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("wmic process where name='OUTLOOK.EXE' get CommandLine");
```

I know I have to split this up somehow but I can't figure out how.

full method looks like :

```
    public static void sendmail() throws IOException {

        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("wmic process where name='OUTLOOK.EXE' get CommandLine");
        final Process p=pb.start();

        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while((line=br.readLine())!=null) sb.append(line);


        System.out.println(sb.toString());

}
```

Comment: Can you describe how you run the command in PowerShell/CMD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separate the command argument should work.

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class WmicProcessRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("wmic", "process", "where", "name='OUTLOOK.EXE'", "get",
                    "CommandLine");
            processBuilder.inheritIO();
            Process wmicProcess = processBuilder.start();
            while (wmicProcess.isAlive()) {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            wmicProcess.destroy();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```